# Why does function 'format' show something like this?

Tags: r

I'm wondering why function 'format' show time in this way

```
today<-sys.Date()
format(today,'%B%d%y')
```

and it returns

```
"\u56db \u6708 24 2021"
```

By the way, I've already set the text default coding as UTF-8.

Comment: What's your locale? Try `Sys.getlocale()`

Comment: Did you mean `today<-Sys.Date()` ?